# When is the sum of square roots of the conjugates of an element quadratic?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a totally real number field, denote $\sigma_i\,:\, \mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ its places. Take an element $c\in \mathbb{K}$, assume for simplicity that for all $i$, $\sigma_i(c) >0$, we'll denote by $\sqrt{\sigma_i(c)}$ the positive square root of $\sigma_i(c)$.

Under what conditions on $c$ does there exist a quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}]$ such that for any $k \in \mathbb{K}$,
$$\sum_i \sqrt{\sigma_i(c)} \sigma_i(k) \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}] \,\,\,?$$

Taking $k=1$, we get the sum referred to by the title : $\sum_i \sqrt{\sigma_i(c)}$.

For quadratic fields $\mathbb{K}$, say $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, all the equations we get are equivalent : 
$$\sqrt{\sigma_1(c)}+\sqrt{\sigma_2(c)} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}] \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sigma_1(c)}- \sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sigma_2(c)} \in \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{D}] $$
since the product of these two expressions is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

For quadratic fields, I derived by hands that the condition is that the norm of $c$ : $N(c)=\sigma_1(c)\sigma_2(c)$ be a rational square.

For general fields $\mathbb{K}$, if $c$ verifies the condition, so does $k^2\times c$ for any $k\in \mathbb{K}$ (edit: we need $k$ to be positive at every place of $\mathbb{K}$ aswell), moreover it seems that any $c$ inside a quadratic subfield $\mathbb{K}'$ of $\mathbb{K}$ such that $N_{\mathbb{K}'}(c)$ is a rational square should work.

Are these elements and their multiple by a square in $\mathbb{K}$ the only solutions ?